# pass variable in ssh

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ssh

I want to pass a variable in ssh. Remote OS is not Unix/Linux.It is Ericsson SmartEdge OS.

Content of newentry.txt
seq 10 deny ip host 1.2.3.4 any

My syntax is

```
ENTRY=`head -1 /scripts/newentry.txt`
ssh user@10.10.10.10 "configure; context NS; ip access-list NS_OUT; $ENTRY;"
```

When I run the script it's shows following`

ENTRY=`head -1 $NEWENTRY_PATH`
++ head -1 /scripts/zabbix/newentry.txt
+ ENTRY='seq 50 deny ip host 1.2.3.4 any'

ssh user@10.10.10.10 "context NS; show ip access-list NS_OUT" | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1}1' > $ACL_PATH
+ ssh user@10.10.10.10 'context NS; show ip access-list NS_OUT'
+ tail -2
+ head -1
+ awk '{$1=$1}1'
user@10.10.10.10's password:

awk '{
    print "seq '$NEWSEQUENCENUMBER' deny ip host '$NEWIPSOURCEADDRESS' any" 
    }' $ACL_PATH > $NEWENTRY_PATH
+ awk '{
    print "seq 50 deny ip host 1.2.3.4 any" 
    }' /scripts/zabbix/acl.txt
sed '1d' $ATTACKERS_PATH > /dev/null
+ sed 1d /scripts/zabbix/attackers.txt

ssh user@10.10.10.10 'configure; context NS; ip access-list NS_OUT; echo $ENTRY;"'
+ ssh user@10.10.10.10 'configure; context NS; ip access-list NS_OUT; echo $ENTRY;"'
user@10.10.10.10's password: 
Unmatched ".
printf "%s\n" "$ENTRY"
+ printf '%s\n' 'seq 50 deny ip host 1.2.3.4 any'
seq 50 deny ip host 1.2.3.4 any

Comment: OK, so what is the remote system type/distribution?

Comment: (1) Is the `ENTRY` variable being set correctly?  If you say `printf "%s\n" "$ENTRY"`, does it display what you expect?  (2) Can you give us a hint what the value of `$ENTRY` is?  Is it a command?  (3) What happens when you run your commands?  … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: The output that you posted doesn't seem to correspond to the script that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

If you use

```
ssh pvt@192.168.1.133 "~/tools/run_pvt.pl $BUILD_NUMBER"
```

instead of

```
ssh pvt@192.168.1.133 '~/tools/run_pvt.pl $BUILD_NUMBER'
```

your shell will interpolate the $BUILD_NUMBER before sending the command string to the remote host.

Comment: mdpc it is Ericsson SmartEdge OS

Comment: dbkonXepts You mean that I must run the script in ssh string?